# Debugging an Outlook Add-in with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging, office-addins

How can you setup the Visual Studio 2013 debugger to attach to a Outlook 2013 add-in for debugging? All of the solutions I am able to find say you can set the start-up application by going to Project Properties in Visual Studio > Debug > Start external application, but there doesn't seem to be such an option in Visual Studio 2013.

If possible, please include all of the steps required to begin debugging a COM Add-in on Outlook 2013/Windows 8.1 with Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Why not just use the `debug` -> `Attach to process...` option and pick Outlook.exe from the list?

Comment: I tried that, but it tells me that no symbols are loaded, so I can't hit breakpoints. Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: The option is there also in VS 2013. It might be named differently depending on the type of your project though. What kind of project and what language do you have?

Comment: Do you deploy the `.pdb` files with the outlook addin?

Comment: @0xA3 It is a Visual C++ project.

Comment: @jessehouwing there is a .pdb file being created when I build the project. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @user3798678: I removed the .NET tag and added the Visual C++ tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to configure the path to Outlook under Project -> Properties -> Debugging:

[image]

If a pdb file is not created, check the settings under Project -> Properties -> C/C++. The entry *Debug Infomartion Format* should be set to create a *Program Database*:

[image]

Comment: Setting outlook.exe as the Command is helpful, as it's now opening Outlook, but now I'm getting an error `Debugging information for 'Outlook.exe' cannot be found or does not match. Cannot find or open the PDB file. Do you want to continue debugging?`

It seems that this is now trying to debug Outlook, rather than the add-in that I'm developing. Any pointers on how to get it connected to the specific add-in? I've tried putting the PDB generated by the add-in in the same folder as Outlook, but that hasn't worked either. I may be missing something, as I am new to Visual Studio and this project.

Comment: @user3798678: Just ignore that message. You ain't going to need the symbol files for outlook.exe, just put breakpoints in your code and the debugger should break. You are in fact debugging the Outlook process, but this is also what you want, because your add-in gets executed within the Outlook process.

Comment: I did try that, but still my breakpoints are not hit. If I mouseover a breakpoint, it says `The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.`

Comment: @user3798678: Probably you registered another version of the add-in than the one in the output folder of your add-in project. It's the dll in the output folder that has to be loaded into the outlook.exe process, otherwise no breakpoint will be hit.

Answer (score -1):

Just debug--> Attach should work.